# Azure SQL cross-database queries using Microsoft Entra

Tags: azure-sql-database

Is it even possible to perform cross-database queries in Azure SQL Database using Microsoft Entra (previously known as Azure Active Directory)?  For security, we have disabled all SQL accounts and use our Entra accounts (our emails) to access our Azure SQL Databases.

All the examples, and help from Copilot, seem to use database scoped credentials and secret keys.

I can create the objects in SQL (credential, source, external table) without any syntax errors but when I query my table I see this error:

These are my steps:

```
create database scoped credential TestDbCred with identity = 'myemail@live.com';

create external data source TestDbSource 
with 
(
    type = RDBMS,
    location = 'myserver.database.windows.net',
    database_name = 'MyDatabase',
    credential = TestDbCred
);

create external table MyTestTable
( 
    Id int not null, 
    Descr nvarchar(max) null
)
with
( 
    data_source = TestDbSource,
    schema = dbo,
    object_name = MyTestTable
);
```

My query:
`SELECT * FROM MyTestTable;`

Results when I attempt to query:

> "Fail to obtain or decrypt secret for credential 'TestDbCred'."

Any help and ideas are very much appreciated!

Comment: As per this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical?view=azuresql#database-scoped-master-key-and-credentials) Authentication using Microsoft Entra ID (formerly Azure Active Directory) with elastic queries is not currently supported.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic queries (cross-database queries) are only supported when connecting with SQL Server Authentication. You can learn more about it on [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-overview?view=azuresql#connectivity-for-tools).

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I will review the documentation more closely and share this info with my team.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic query feature is the way for cross database queries and
As per MSFT current feature of elastic query, only SQL auth is supported
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help!  We will take another approach...